# Handling form POST submit

Tags: angular, forms

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="fgTest" action="http://..." target="_self"  method="POST" 
 #testCase>
  <input type="hidden" formControlName="test" name="test" />
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild("testCase") testCase;

ngOnInit() {
  this.fgTest = this.fb.group({
      "test": JSON.stringify(...)
    });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.testCase.nativeElement.submit();
}
```

My question is how could Angular get notified if `action`, which redirects to another URL, fails for some reason? Is there a way to apply some **error handling** in this POST request on the client?

Comment: The only thing you can do is send the form with the angular's http client and _after_ that redirects whereever you need. The way you showed it's impossible.

Comment: You should probably consider the approach of sending data to back-end services using a custom angular service component. This way you  remain in control.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does not work that way. In your angular controlled form, you should handle "submit" or at least have a button click handled which will in turn do and http request.

```
<form [formGroup]="fgTest" 
 #testCase>
  <input type="hidden" formControlName="test" name="test" />
<button (click)="submitForm()">
</form>
```

then in the code file...

```
submitForm(){
   this.httpClient.post("url", data).subscribe((result)=> {do stuff} );
}
```